# What is the best practice to inherit common props and methods in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in React so please guide me on this. I want to make a common parent component which serves as a template for actual implementation of components. It will hold common props and methods. Components inherited from that component can manipulate the props in different ways like some may give it default value, some may not require them etc. Its somewhat like abstract class in Java.

Example use case:
I want to make components for different input types like number, date, etc. I want to write a common BaseInputComponent which will look something like this:

```
<BaseInputComponent
   type={..}
   value={..}
   placeholder={..}
   ...
/>
```

I may then write different components like

```
class DateInput extends BaseInputComponent {...}
```

But I read somewhere that it is not a good practice. Composition is more preferred over inheritance in React. But I don't know how to use that in practice?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

From the link: *At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.*

Comment: I think the new context API in React 16.3.0 is what you're looking for. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html

Answer (score 2):

You can import your BaseInputComponent like this

```
import BaseInputComponent from './baseInputComponent'

class DateInput extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
 }
...

 render(){
  return(
   <BaseInputComponent type={date} value='20-12-2018' placeholder='Date' />
  )
 }

}
```